# Joomla 2.5 Custom Search Page, Display modules

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I literally been to page 18 of Google, Anyways, All I need to do is create a custom search results page, where you can assign specific modules to it.

Using Universal Live Ajax search module

Because if the modules aren't set to "display on all pages" it doesn't show on the search results page.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after looking at normal search and universal live Ajax search.. there is a parameter missing from universal live Ajax search, which links it to the custom search page made...

The standard search has the parameter of "Itemid" and universal live Ajax search doesn't, so temporarily i hard-coded my hidden search pages item id in Ajax search, by adding the following line of code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="THE ID OF YOUR HIDDEN MENU ITEM HERE" />
```

underneath line 188 this line, `<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_search" />` in joomlasite/modules/mod_universal_ajaxlivesearch/mod_universal_ajaxlivesearch.php

Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason modules do not display when you not set pages option to `"display on all pages"` or to `specific pages` because you dont have `itemid` on that perticular page.You can create a menu for the component and than assign modules to this menu.Create a hidden field in the search form for itemid if it's not there and set `itemid` value in the field.

Hope this will help.